# Is there a generalization of these Free-like constructions?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, free-monad

I was playing around with free-like ideas, and found this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data Monoid m = Monoid { mempty :: m, mappend :: m -> m -> m }
data Generator a m = Generator { monoid :: Monoid m, singleton :: a -> m }

newtype Free f = Free { getFree :: forall s. f s -> s }

mkMonoid :: (forall s. f s -> Monoid s) -> Monoid (Free f)
mkMonoid f = Monoid {
    mempty = Free (mempty . f),
    mappend = \a b -> Free $ \s -> mappend (f s) (getFree a s) (getFree b s)
}

freeMonoid :: Monoid (Free Monoid)
freeMonoid = mkMonoid id

mkGenerator :: (forall s. f s -> Generator a s) -> Generator a (Free f)
mkGenerator f = Generator {
    monoid = mkMonoid (monoid . f),
    singleton = \x -> Free $ \s -> singleton (f s) x
}

freeGenerator :: Generator a (Free (Generator a))
freeGenerator = mkGenerator id
```

I would like to find the conditions under which I could write a funcion:

```
mkFree :: (??? f) => f (Free f)
```

but I have been unable to find a meaningful structure for `f` (other than the trivial one in which `mkFree` is a method of `???`) which would allow this function to be written.  In particular, my aesthetic sense would prefer if this structure did not mention the `Free` type.

Has anyone seen something like this before?  Is this generalization possible? Is there a known generalization in a direction that I have not thought of yet?

Comment: I have this on Hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-functors-0.1.1, but I don't think that's what you want?

Comment: Right, after matching what you have to my package, I think I understand what you want. Translated it would be how to automatically generate an instance `Monoid (Free Monoid a)`, or generally an instance `c (Free c a)`. F.e. the `Num` instance here: https://github.com/sjoerdvisscher/free-functors/blob/master/examples/FreeNum.hs. It is basically `liftAn` plus some noise for the simple cases, which should be solvable with some template haskell. But I think the completely generic case is quite complicated.

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher, it's that noise that I'm interested in (that's why I'm using data types and not classes here).  It feels like `Traversable`, but it works on negative occurrences of the parameter, too.  I was wondering if there's an algebraic property (like `Traversable`) rather than structural (introspecting type signatures) from which this instance could be generated.

Comment: With noise I meant newtype (un)wrapping. I.e. `mappend = \(Free a) (Free b) -> Free $ liftA3 mappend f a b`. Perhaps SPJs recent proposal could help: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/NewtypeWrappers

Comment: I think this is what in universal algebra is called a [Variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) but I am not a mathematician.  I'll think about it

Comment: @Philip JF, here Wikipedia mentions varieties and free objects in one paragraph, that should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object#Existence

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The link to universal algebra was a good starting point, and after reading up on it a bit everything fell into place. What we're looking for is an F-algebra:

```
type Alg f x = f x -> x
```

for any (endo)functor `f`. For example, for a Monoid algebra the functor is:

```
data MonoidF m = MEmpty | MAppend m m deriving Functor
```

For any `Monoid` instance there's the obvious monoid algebra:

```
monoidAlg :: Monoid m => Alg MonoidF m
monoidAlg MEmpty = mempty
monoidAlg (MAppend a b) = mappend a b
```

Now we can take the free functor definition from the free-functors package, and replace the class constraint with the f-algebra:

```
newtype Free f a = Free { runFree :: forall b. Alg f b -> (a -> b) -> b }
```

The free functor is in some sense the best way to turn any set `a` into an algebra. This is how:

```
unit :: a -> Free f a
unit a = Free $ \_ k -> k a
```

It is the best way because for any other way to turn `a` into an algebra `b`, we can give a function from the free algebra to `b`:

```
rightAdjunct :: Functor f => Alg f b -> (a -> b) -> Free f a -> b
rightAdjunct alg k (Free f) = f alg k
```

What is left is to actually show that the free functor creates an f-algebra (and this is what you asked for):

```
freeAlg :: Functor f => Alg f (Free f a)
freeAlg ff = Free $ \alg k -> alg (fmap (rightAdjunct alg k) ff)
```

To explain a bit: `ff` is of type `f (Free f a)` and we need to build a `Free f a`. We can do that if we can build a `b`, given `alg :: f b -> b` and `k :: a -> b`. So we can apply `alg` to `ff` if we can map every `Free f a` it contains to a `b`, but that's exactly what `rightAdjunct` does with `alg` and `k`.

As you might have guessed, this `Free f` is the free monad on the functor `f` (the [church encoded version](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.3.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free-Church.html) to be precise.)

```
instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
  return = unit
  m >>= f = rightAdjunct freeAlg f m
```

Comment: Thanks! I also came to this realization yesterday.  Thanks for taking the time to write it up!

Comment: NP, the pleasure of learning this stuff was all mine! Do you need this for something?